# Search in Laravel relation using json column

Tags: laravel

I have problem with search in json column.

I have 3 relations:

- products
- feature products
- feature_values

My tables:

- products: https://ibb.co/1dgjT6m
- feature products: https://ibb.co/K9f74Wn
- feature_values: https://ibb.co/rc3zG5W

My migrations:

Product:

```
class Product extends Model implements Presentable
{
....
public function featureProducts()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(FeatureProduct::class, 'product_id');
        //return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class, 'feature_product', 'id');
    }
}
```

FeatureProduct

```
class FeatureProduct extends Model
{
    protected $table = "feature_product";

    protected $with = [
        'values'
    ];

    public function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(FeatureValue::class, 'feature_values_ids', 'id');
    }

}
```

FeatureValues:

```
class FeatureValue extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes,
        Translatable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'feature_id',
        'value'
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    protected $translatable = [
        'value'
    ];

    public function feature(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Feature::class);
    }

    public function getAdminUrlAttribute(): AbstractAdminUrlPresenter
    {
        return new FeatureValueUrlPresenter($this);
    }
}
```

I need to show products with features and assigned features_values

I heve problem with search in json column: feature_product. feature_values_ids

When I have INT in this column, then this is working fine:

```
public function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(FeatureValue::class, 'feature_values_ids', 'id');
    }
```

When I have:

```
["1", "2","3"]
```

I haven't any results :(

Haw can I repair it?

Comment: If you need a many to many relationship, you should use a pivot table. one to many: add a column feature_product_id col in feature_values to make the relation. BelongsTo is only for a one to one relation, so it expects a int value

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And how to solve the above issue when I have json instead of NUMBER? I cannot modify the table layout :(

Comment: Hmmz, thats not a good way of making relationships, but is this a solution: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations